# RAM full in numpy sagemath

Tags: python, numpy, ram, sage

I wrote the next code. In 1-2 hours of execution time the RAM of my laptop (8gb) is filled and the sistem crash:

```
from scipy.stats import uniform    
import numpy as np

cant_de_cadenas =[700,800,900]

cantidad_de_cadenas=np.array([])

for kkkkk in cant_de_cadenas:
    cantidad_de_cadenas=np.append(cantidad_de_cadenas,kkkkk)    

cantidad_de_cadenas=np.transpose(cantidad_de_cadenas)

b=10
h=b
Longitud=1
numero_experimentos=100

densidad_de_cadenas =cantidad_de_cadenas/(b**2)

prob_perc=np.array([])

tiempos=np.array([])

S_int=np.array([])

S_medio=np.array([])

desviacion_standard=np.array([])

desviacion_standard_nuevo=np.array([])

anisotropia_macroscopica_porcentual=np.array([])

componente_y=np.array([])

componente_x=np.array([])

import time

for N in cant_de_cadenas:

    empieza=time.clock()

    PERCOLACION=np.array([])

    size_medio_intuitivo = np.array([])
    size_medio_nuevo = np.array([]) 
    std_dev_size_medio_intuitivo = np.array([])     
    std_dev_size_medio_nuevo = np.array([]) 
    comp_y = np.array([])   
    comp_x = np.array([])


    for u in xrange(numero_experimentos):


        perco = False

        array_x1=uniform.rvs(loc=-b/2, scale=b, size=N)  
        array_y1=uniform.rvs(loc=-h/2, scale=h, size=N)  
        array_angle=uniform.rvs(loc=-0.5*(np.pi), scale=np.pi, size=N)  


        array_pendiente_x=1./np.tan(array_angle)

        random=uniform.rvs(loc=-1, scale=2, size=N)
        lambda_sign=np.zeros([N])
        for t in xrange(N):
            if random[t]<0:
                lambda_sign[t]=-1
            else:
                lambda_sign[t]=1
        array_lambdas=(lambda_sign*Longitud)/np.sqrt(1+array_pendiente_x**2) 


        array_x2= array_x1 + array_lambdas*array_pendiente_x
        array_y2= array_y1 + array_lambdas*1

        array_x1 = np.append(array_x1, [-b/2, b/2, -b/2, -b/2])
        array_y1 = np.append(array_y1, [-h/2, -h/2, -h/2, h/2])
        array_x2 = np.append(array_x2, [-b/2, b/2, b/2, b/2])
        array_y2 = np.append(array_y2, [h/2, h/2, -h/2, h/2])

        M = np.zeros([N+4,N+4])  

        for j in xrange(N+4):
            if j>0:
                x_A1B1 = array_x2[j]-array_x1[j]
                y_A1B1 = array_y2[j]-array_y1[j]
                x_A1A2 = array_x1[0:j]-array_x1[j]
                y_A1A2 = array_y1[0:j]-array_y1[j]      
                x_A2A1 = -1*x_A1A2
                y_A2A1 = -1*y_A1A2
                x_A2B2 = array_x2[0:j]-array_x1[0:j]
                y_A2B2 = array_y2[0:j]-array_y1[0:j]
                x_A1B2 = array_x2[0:j]-array_x1[j]
                y_A1B2 = array_y2[0:j]-array_y1[j]
                x_A2B1 = array_x2[j]-array_x1[0:j]
                y_A2B1 = array_y2[j]-array_y1[0:j]

                p1 = x_A1B1*y_A1A2 - y_A1B1*x_A1A2
                p2 = x_A1B1*y_A1B2 - y_A1B1*x_A1B2
                p3 = x_A2B2*y_A2B1 - y_A2B2*x_A2B1
                p4 = x_A2B2*y_A2A1 - y_A2B2*x_A2A1

                condicion_1=p1*p2
                condicion_2=p3*p4                         

                for k in xrange (j):
                    if condicion_1[k]<=0 and condicion_2[k]<=0:
                        M[j,k]=1
                del condicion_1
                del condicion_2


            if j+1<N+4:
                x_A1B1 = array_x2[j]-array_x1[j]
                y_A1B1 = array_y2[j]-array_y1[j]
                x_A1A2 = array_x1[j+1:]-array_x1[j]
                y_A1A2 = array_y1[j+1:]-array_y1[j]     
                x_A2A1 = -1*x_A1A2
                y_A2A1 = -1*y_A1A2
                x_A2B2 = array_x2[j+1:]-array_x1[j+1:]
                y_A2B2 = array_y2[j+1:]-array_y1[j+1:]
                x_A1B2 = array_x2[j+1:]-array_x1[j]
                y_A1B2 = array_y2[j+1:]-array_y1[j]
                x_A2B1 = array_x2[j]-array_x1[j+1:]
                y_A2B1 = array_y2[j]-array_y1[j+1:]

                p1 = x_A1B1*y_A1A2 - y_A1B1*x_A1A2
                p2 = x_A1B1*y_A1B2 - y_A1B1*x_A1B2
                p3 = x_A2B2*y_A2B1 - y_A2B2*x_A2B1
                p4 = x_A2B2*y_A2A1 - y_A2B2*x_A2A1

                condicion_1=p1*p2
                condicion_2=p3*p4                         

                for k in xrange ((N+4)-j-1):
                    if condicion_1[k]<=0 and condicion_2[k]<=0:
                        M[j,k+j+1]=1   
                del condicion_1
                del condicion_2

        M[N,N+2]=0
        M[N,N+3]=0
        M[N+1,N+2]=0
        M[N+1,N+3]=0
        M[N+2,N]=0
        M[N+2,N+1]=0
        M[N+3,N]=0
        M[N+3,N+1]=0


        CD=np.array([])

        POPOPO=[] 
        for g in xrange(N):

            lala=0
            r=False
            while lala<=len(POPOPO)-1:       
                esta= g in POPOPO[lala]  

                if esta is True:
                    lala=len(POPOPO) 
                    r=True
                else:
                    lala=lala+1
            if r is False:       



                L=np.array([g])        
                for s in xrange(N):
                    if M[g,s] != 0:
                        L=np.append(L,s)

                x=0
                while x<= N:        
                    for l in xrange(N):
                        z= l in L              
                        d=L[x]
                        if z is False and M[d,l] != 0:   
                            L=np.append(L,l)
                    if x+1<len(L):
                        x+=1
                    else:
                        x=N+1.

                q= len (L)
                CD=np.append(CD, q)
                POPOPO.append(L)


        M_horizontal=M.copy()   
        M_horizontal[:,N+2] = np.zeros(N+4)    
        M_horizontal[:,N+3] = np.zeros(N+4)    
        M_horizontal[N+2] = np.zeros(N+4)    
        M_horizontal[N+3] = np.zeros(N+4)    



        L=np.array([N])        
        for s in xrange(N+4):
            if M_horizontal[N,s] != 0:
                L=np.append(L,s)

        x=0
        while x<= N+4:      
            for l in xrange(N+4):
                z= l in L               
                d=L[x]
                if z is False and M_horizontal[d,l] != 0:   
                    L=np.append(L,l)
            if x+1<len(L):
                x+=1
            else:
                x=(N+4)+1.      

        LV1_in_L = N in L 
        LV2_in_L= (N+1) in L

        if LV1_in_L is True and LV2_in_L is True:
            perc_horiz=True
        else:
            perc_horiz=False


        M_vertical=M.copy()    

        M_vertical[:,N] = np.zeros(N+4)    
        M_vertical[:,N+1] = np.zeros(N+4)    
        M_vertical[N] = np.zeros(N+4)    
        M_vertical[N+1] = np.zeros(N+4)    



        L=np.array([N+2])        
        for s in xrange(N+4):
            if M_vertical[N+2,s] != 0:
                L=np.append(L,s)

        x=0
        while x<= N+4:      
            for l in xrange(N+4):
                z= l in L               
                d=L[x]
                if z is False and M_vertical[d,l] != 0:   
                    L=np.append(L,l)
            if x+1<len(L):
                x+=1
            else:
                x=(N+4)+1.      

        LH1_in_L = (N+2) in L  
        LH2_in_L= (N+3) in L

        if LH1_in_L is True and LH2_in_L is True:
            perc_ver = True
        else:
            perc_ver = False



        if perc_ver is True or perc_horiz is True:
            PERCOLACION=np.append(PERCOLACION,1)
            perco=True


        D = np.array([]) 
        W = np.array([])   

        for c in xrange (int(min(CD)), int(max(CD)+1),1):   
            D=np.append(D,c)
            frec = sum (CD == c)   
            W = np.append(W,frec)

        if perco is True:
            posicion=np.argmax(D)
            D=np.delete(D,posicion)
            W=np.delete(W,posicion)

        if len(D) == 0 and len(W)==0:
            S_medio_intuitivo_exp_u=0
            S_medio_nuevo_exp_u = 0
            std_dev_exp_u = 0
            std_dev_nuevo_exp_u = 0
        else:

            S_medio_intuitivo_exp_u = np.average (D,weights=W)   

            peso_nuevo=D*W

            S_medio_nuevo_exp_u = np.average (D,weights=peso_nuevo)


            tipos=sum(W)   
            X=W*((D-S_medio_intuitivo_exp_u)**2)
            S=sum(X)

            std_dev_exp_u = np.sqrt(S/(tipos-1.)) 

            tipos_nuevo=sum(peso_nuevo)    
            X_nuevo=peso_nuevo*((D-S_medio_nuevo_exp_u)**2)
            S_nuevo=sum(X_nuevo)

            std_dev_nuevo_exp_u = np.sqrt(S_nuevo/(tipos_nuevo-1.))  


        componente_longitudinal=Longitud*np.abs(np.cos(array_angle))
        comp_y=np.append(comp_y, sum(componente_longitudinal)/N)

        componente_transversal=Longitud*np.abs(np.sin(array_angle))
        comp_x=np.append(comp_x, sum(componente_transversal)/N) 

        std_dev_size_medio_intuitivo=np.append(std_dev_size_medio_intuitivo, std_dev_exp_u)

        std_dev_size_medio_nuevo=np.append(std_dev_size_medio_nuevo, std_dev_nuevo_exp_u)

        size_medio_intuitivo=np.append(size_medio_intuitivo, S_medio_intuitivo_exp_u)

        size_medio_nuevo=np.append(size_medio_nuevo, S_medio_nuevo_exp_u)


    percolation_probability=sum(PERCOLACION)/numero_experimentos

    prob_perc=np.append(prob_perc, percolation_probability)

    S_int = np.append (S_int, sum(size_medio_intuitivo)/numero_experimentos)

    S_medio=np.append (S_medio, sum(size_medio_nuevo)/numero_experimentos)

    desviacion_standard = np.append (desviacion_standard, sum(std_dev_size_medio_intuitivo)/numero_experimentos)

    desviacion_standard_nuevo=np.append (desviacion_standard_nuevo, sum(std_dev_size_medio_nuevo)/numero_experimentos)

    tiempos=np.append(tiempos, time.clock()-empieza)

    componente_y=np.append(componente_y, sum(comp_y)/numero_experimentos)
    componente_x=np.append(componente_x, sum(comp_x)/numero_experimentos)

    anisotropia_macroscopica_porcentual=100*(1-(componente_y/componente_x))
```

I tryed with gc and gc.collect() and 'del'command for deleting arrays after his use and nothing work!

What am I doing wrong? Why the memory becomes full while running (starts with 10% of RAM used and in 1-2hour is totally full used)?

Lets take an array M with size 300MB. When this is overwritten (for example, in each iteration), have we 300MB occupated in RAM memory or just 300MB? In the case that we have just 300MB, there should be no problem, so why have I this RAM issue? In the case of the RAM is acumulated, how can I do for free RAM memory occupated for the 'old' array?

Please help me, I'm totally stuck!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you post more of your code? Without seeing your actual algorithm it's impossible to know where the problem lies.

Comment: sage uses sympy, and sympy seems to be good for doing stuff, but bad for doing stuff that needs to be done fast/numerical/optimized/... If you can, use numpy and python without involving sympy. Another idea is profiling your code to see where the problematic lines of code are when it comes to RAM-consumption. A third option is to post more code to show us where the problem might lie

Comment: I would also add that [`memory_profiler`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler/0.9) can be very useful for troubleshooting this sort of thing

Comment: Hi experts I edit my post with a extended version of the code. Please help!

Comment: `srange`? What's `srange`?

Comment: When you strip down code to post it, strip it down to something that actually runs and actually demonstrates the problem when you run it. We can't tell if the problem is in something you tore out.

Comment: I edit the post pasting a executable code. Waiting for your answers. Thanks a lot!

Comment: do you still need to solve this? (and can you post your codenames in english instead of spanish? that tends to make it more readable to people that want to help you)